# Is there anyway to generate a pdf file with a timestamp or something that sign it to prove that will always be immutable?

Tags: c#, security, pdf, hash, sha256

after the elaboration of an automatic process, i have to export a pdf and save it automatically in a standard path.
every time that the pdf should be export it, should have a timestamp and something to prove that this is authentic and nobody has modified it.

i need to implement it in C# with my new driver, i'm reading about the SHA256, but i'm seeing that every time the pdf is opened the hash become different because the metadata is changed in pdf document.

is there anyway to implent this functionality in a simple way?
Thank you

Comment: Read about pdf signatures. These are supported by pdfs by design.

Comment: *"i need to implement it in C# with my new driver, i'm reading about the SHA256, but i'm seeing that every time the pdf is opened the hash become different because the metadata is changed in pdf document."* - What programs change the hash of a PDF simply by opening it?

Comment: @mkl: He's probably computing the hash of the entire file, instead of just the contents that a PDF signature is supposed to cover.  For example, adding a second signature most certainly modifies the file, but should not invalidate an earlier signature, as it does not modify the context stream the signature applies to.

Comment: Maybe. But he explicitly mentions metadata...